# XSLT for Creation of XML fields based on input

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to write an XSLT program where i would need to perform below steps.

1. add some extra static xml fields
2. Append some characters to each xml tag
3. Occurance should also be consiered
4. If any empty tags or no tags comes in input payload then it should not create that particular tag in output

Can someone please help me out on the same. Thank you.

**Input XML**

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <Header>
            <Item1> 
                <text>data1</text>
                <text2>data2</text2>
            </Item1>
            <ItemMAIN>  
                <Item2> 
                    <text3>data3</text3>
                    <text4>data4</text4>
                </Item2>
            </ItemMAIN> 
            <Item3> 
                <text5>data5</text5>
                <text6>data6</text6>
            </Item3>
            <Item3> 
                <text5>data7</text5>
                <text6>data8</text6>
            </Item3>
            <Item3> 
                <text5>data9</text5>
    
            </Item3>
            <Item4> 
                <text5>data10</text5>
                <text6/>
            </Item4>
        </Header>
    </root>
```

**Output XML :**

```
    <soap:TestEnvelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:mp="http://example.com" xmlns:kt="http://exampleKT.com" >
    <soap:Headdata>
        <kt:name>   
            <mp:Item1>  
                <mp:text>data1</mp:text>
                <mp:text2>data2</mp:text2>
            </mp:Item1>
        </kt:name>  
    </soap:Headdata>
    <soap:Bodydata1>
        <kt:name>   
            <mp:Item2>  
                <mp:text3>data3</mp:text3>
                <mp:text4>data4</mp:text4>
            </mp:Item2>
        </kt:name>  
    </soap:Bodydata1>
    <soap:Bodydata2>
        <kt:name>   
            <mp:Item3>  
                <mp:text5>data5</mp:text5>
                <mp:text6>data6</mp:text6>
            </mp:Item3>
        </kt:name>  
        <kt:name>   
            <mp:Item3>  
                <mp:text5>data7</mp:text5>
                <mp:text6>data8</mp:text6>
            </mp:Item3>
        </kt:name>  
        <kt:name>   
            <mp:Item3>  
                <mp:text5>data9</mp:text5>
            </mp:Item3>
        </kt:name>  
    </soap:Bodydata2>
    <soap:Bodydata3>
        <kt:name>   
            <mp:Item4>  
                <mp:text5>data10</mp:text5>
            </mp:Item4>
        </kt:name>  
    </soap:Bodydata3>
</soap:TestEnvelope>
```

**Tried XSLT Code :** I tried like below but it gives me impression that i am trying to hardcode each field. But would like to have a code that i can use if there is any extra xml field in future should also be handled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soap:TestEnvelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:mp="http://example.com" xmlns:kt="http://exampleKT.com" >
            <soap:Headdata>
                <xsl:for-each select="/root/Header">
                    <kt:name>   
                        <mp:text>   
                            <xsl:value-of select="Item1/text"/>
                        </mp:text>  
                        <mp:text2>  
                            <xsl:value-of select="Item1/text2"/>
                        </mp:text2>
                    </kt:name>
                </soap:Headdata>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/Header/ItemMAIN">               
                <soap:Bodydata1>
                    <kt:name>
                        <mp:text3>  
                            <xsl:value-of select="Item2/text3"/>
                        </mp:text3> 
                        <mp:text4>  
                            <xsl:value-of select="Item2/text4"/>
                        </mp:text4> 
                    </kt:name>
                </soap:Bodydata1>
            </xsl:for-each>
                    :
                    :
                    :
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="*[not(*)][not(normalize-space())]" />

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you need namespaces, add a namespace to the element function, and it will all be handled with the XSLT-processor, depending and correct in conjunction with the declared namespaces in top of the result-xml.

Like this:

`<xsl:param name="ns" select="string('https://a_namespace/')"/>`

`<xsl:element name="AnElement" namespace="{$ns}">`